# Should tags be created for each specific platform, instead of having a general tag for every platform?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

I tagged a game and used the PC tag to let the users know I am specifically talking about the PC version. I then read the tag properly to realize that the PC isn't used at all to tag a version of a game.

After a bit of research, I noticed that in order to specify a platform, you need to create a new platform-specific version of that tag. This can end up causing a few problems like:

1 - Someone might be the first one to talk about [tasg:minecraft-xbox], and they don't have the reputation to create a new tag.
2 - People might ignore this [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) tag, if they subscribed to simply [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft). They would have to subscribe to every possible version of that tag in order to see all minecraft related questions.
3 - Some people who can create tags will simply create a [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) tag, but if it is too specific, the tag will get deleted after some time leaving that question with invalid tags.

Yes, you can possibly specify the version you are referring to in the title - but like it has been discussed a lot of times over the past on many Stack Exchange sites, things that should be in tag *shouldn't* be in the title.

I can very well live with the fact that we need to create a tag for each version of each game but it seems like a big effort compared to simply having a tag for each platforms like the "PC Version" or "Xbox Version" tags.

Comment: [Minecraft-console](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) doesn't do the trick?  Minecraft is in a special boat, due to the various platforms having different functionality.

Comment: It does the trick. The problem is there is minecraft console, pc, mobile, raspberry pi and who knows where else theyll release it. Simply subscribing to the minecraft tag would make it way easier. Then platform tag could make a question more specific and it could be used for every game that need the same specification without having to create another tag for them too

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8124/tagging-minecraft-for-consoles.  That's where the current tag usage come in.

Comment: @Frank I actually did read this before posting which is why my question focuses on the fact that version and games shouldnt be in the same tags at all. Also the current way to go gives a problem when you try to be specific between xbox and ps4 versions.

Comment: You can subscribe to `minecraft*` and get everything Minecraft related.

Comment: Yes you can. that solves one of the issue but i still think its overkill to create a tag everytime

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - It's also worth noting that the auto-tag cleanup is turned **off** on Arqade. It means we are more vigilant with tags, but also means that questions for games don't end up in [untagged] in 6 months after being the only question for that game